# What did I do wrong with this edit?

Tags: support, status-completed, rejected-edits

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27393797) yesterday, which I think makes several worthwhile improvements, as I described in the comment:

> More recent versions of the documentation in question calls the parameter delta instead of epsilon. Updated to reflect that, to include a link to the docs, and remove redundant text.

To elaborate a little:

- As the second-top answer mentioned, the parameter is definitely called `delta` not `epsilon` in all versions of the documentation I can find, indeed a Google search for "junit assertequals double epsilon" returns 28,000 hits, compared to 123,000 for "junit assertequals double delta". So it seemed a good change to include both names to aid searchability.
- I included a link to the latest version of the documentation that was quoted, because that just seemed like common sense.
- I removed a parenthetical question about Epsilon being a letter in the Greek alphabet, because it seemed redundant.
- I removed a secondary question "can someone explain how to use it?". At the time it felt redundant, as understanding what the parameter means surely implies that you will understand how to use it? With hindsight I suppose that doesn't necessarily follow. I'm still not sure that it added much to the question though - a good answer will surely always include how something should be used where that's relevant?

The edit was rejected by two reviewers. The first reviewer's reason is:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I don't believe this is true. I don't think there's any deviation from the intent whatsoever, with the possible exception of my final bullet point above.

The second reviewer's reason is:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Which is also not true, I don't address the author at all, I simply update the details of the question to match the current documentation.

I'm pretty confident I've met all the requirements on the [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) page in the help, which says:

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

I think I did pretty much all of those things, and did no harm.

I realise, of course, that this is one fairly trivial edit on a fairly niche and trivial question of limited value to the world at large, and don't want to seem like I'm whining that these nasty people cruelly rejected my lovely edit, I'd just like to understand if I did something wrong to understand how to avoid the same thing next time.

Comment: @BSMP I don't think so, I didn't edit any code. The quote from the help page is just the same thing I quoted in my question and, as I said, I believe I met all of those points. Was there something in one of the references that you specifically meant me to read? I've skimmed them all and can't see anything that really shows something I did wrong.

Comment: Appears to be an okay edit. I've overridden the rejection.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, thank you - and I got a badge for updating the tags too - hurrah! :D

Comment: @SamuelLiew Why is this tagged [tag:status-completed]? That is for bug reports and feature requests ...

Comment: @David Well, there was an action performed (approving the rejected edit), so I assume that's what he was referring to with the tag.